# visible vanilla dashboard to only one ip-address (admin)

Tags: vanilla-forums

```
http://fidm.in/vanilla/
```

I want to restrict these two urls

[1]: http://fidm.in/vanilla/dashboard/settings , http://fidm.in/vanilla/settings outside my ip-address.

I have tried through .htacess but no success.

Comment: http://fidm.in/t1/wp-admin, Like this wordpress is redirecting to google.com i did , but not able to it for vanilla forums

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /t1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /t1/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=117.215.247.103
RewriteRule ^(wp-admin) http://google.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

If .htaccess not work.you try php custom code $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Go to applications/dashboard/views/settings folder

and use custom coding in index.php

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '00.00.00.00'){
header('Location: http://www.rediect-domain.com/');
exit;
```

}